# User options in another table: what is the best practice to check if an option is there?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several option that a user can have, mainly to validate his presence around the site.

Tables are like this:

Users:

```
id=1
username=stackoverflow
password=oSKAJMMS;
address=xyz
...
```

Options:

```
user_id=1
option=AD3
```

---

```
user_id=1
option=AC1
```

At some point I need to check if he has a particular option (like: AD3, AC1 etc) in the "options" table, minding that an user with no option simply doesn't exist in the "options" table.

What is the best practice for this? I though about a JOIN but every time I read stackoverflow I find out simpler and more effective methods, so I ask you what should I do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users u
WHERE   EXISTS (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    options o
        WHERE   o.user_id = u.id
                AND o.option = 'AC1'
        )
```

Make sure you have an index on `options (user_id, option)`

Comment: Thanks, I first tried without the index and the query took 33 seconds!
Also I learned that you can set users u and use u in the query, I've never known such a thing, thank you!